# CORS in Spring Boot with Spring Security + React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

After deploy I got problem with CORS. I can access data directly from my API but when trying fetch it from React app I got problem as in an image:

[image: Image of headers from console]

I tried to add filters to add to every header Access-Control-Allow-Origin and it now return data from API and I can see it in browsers console but react cant get it

WebSecurity.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and();

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean crosFilterRegistration(){
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new MyCorsFilter());
    registrationBean.setName("CORS Filter");
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setOrder(1);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("https://*************"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin",
            "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

MyCorseFiltre.java

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://**************");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("https://*************");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This row

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://**************");
```

adds the duplicated header. So does this row:

```
configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("https://*************"));
```

One of them is enough. Preferably the latter. The same goes for most of the CORS config you have.

Comment: Thank you for rsponse, I did comment all filters except last one and still get duplicated header. What can cause such problem?